# The use of p-values in tests of d-separation

Tags: p-value, causality, structural-equation-modeling, type-i-and-ii-errors, d-separation

In his very helpful online [book](https://jslefche.github.io/sem_book/local-estimation.html) on structural equation modeling, Jon Lefcheck writes the following concerning d-separation tests for SEMs:

> Once the model is fit, statistical independence is assessed with a t-, F-, or other test. If the resulting P-value is >0.05, then we fail to reject the null hypothesis that the two variables are conditionally independent. In this case, a high P-value is a good thing: it indicates that we were justified in excluding that relationship from our path diagram in the first place, because the data don’t support a strong linkage between those variables within some tolerance for error.

My understanding is that this is a standard procedure in SEM and more broadly in DAG-data consistency checks, not a quirk of Lefcheck's workflow. My question is, doesn't this amount to an attempt to use p-values to control type II error rate?

Setting aside the inherent limitations of p-values even when used [correctly](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/0956797613504966), the fundamental problem is that p-values simply *don't* control type II error rate --- they control type I error rate.

The language in the documentation of the R package [`bnlearn`](https://rpubs.com/sarataheri/bnlearnCGM), a suite of Bayesian causal discovery tools, is even more explicit in equating the failure to reject the null hypothesis of zero correlation with the *acceptance* of the null hypothesis, i.e. the conclusion that correlation is "in fact" zero:

> Now, let’s check whether the global Markov property is satisfied in this example. We will use the survey data to check the Null hypothesis that S is independent of T given O and R. In R, we can use ci.test function from bnlearn to find conditional dependence. [...] As you can see, the p-value is greater than 0.05 threshold, hence we do not reject the Null hypothesis and conclude that in fact, S is independent of T given O and R.

As a convert to causal inference and Bayesian logic from the cult of cause-blind null-hypothesis statistical testing, I find it frustrating that when it comes time to validate our causal graphs --- after all our effort to construct principled causal models and estimate parameters informatively --- we fall back on p-values, and a dubious use of p-values at that.

Am I missing something? I hope to be corrected.

Comment: The conclusion beginning with 'In this case, a high P-value is a good thing...' is based on a common but mistaken premise. Lack of power to reject a null is not sufficient reason to assert it to be true

Comment: @Glen_b yes, that's exactly my concern. And yet it seems that this use of p-values is completely normative in the world of d-separation testing. I'm baffled. The Heckerman et al. reference mentioned by Scriddie below addresses this issue, but I'm left wondering why this is buried in a 2006 book chapter.

Answer (score 5):

This is an excellent question.

You're right in that testing for independence relies on some sort of significance threshold, and this is a challenge whenever one wants to discover properties of the DAG structure from data.
Do I understand correctly that you're taking issue with the phrase "*it indicates that we were justified in excluding that relationship from our path diagram in the first place*"?
Indeed, the p-value doesn't give us this type of information as it assumes that the Null hypothesis is true in the first place.
That said, I don't think it's correct to say that testing for DAG relationships per se relies on dubious ways of using p-values, just because the source you're quoting doesn't give an entirely accurate interpretation.

Regarding the use of p-values for finding edges in causal DAGs in general, I think it's useful to recall that causal models are extensions of statistical models. When there is a statistical relationship, it may or may not be causal. But, under the causal faithfulness assumption, when there is no statistical relationship, there is no causal one either. So causal models cannot do away with the need to establish statistical relationships.

Comment: I suppose I'm more inclined to think of statistical models as extensions of causal models, but I take your point that the two go hand-in-hand. My main concern is that the use of p-values in tests of d-separation controls the long-run rate of wrongly rejecting the hypothesis of (conditional) independence, when we should be controlling is the long-run rate of wrongly rejecting the hypothesis of (conditional) **dependence**.

Secondarily, it irks me that the best we can do is a yes/no threshold rather than some quantification of evidence.

Comment: Inverting the null hypothesis would be very interesting indeed, but as far as I know there isn't a good approach on how to do that out there. As for the threshold and uncertainty quantification, I think there are some Bayesian approaches like [this one](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-33486-6_1), and this is an active area of research, if that's any comfort.